# How to create a create_index python method for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

in mongodb's cmd you use the command:

```
db.test2.createIndex({ "type" : 1, "amount" : 1, "loss" : 1, "price" : 1, "create_date" : 1 }, {unique:true})
```

in python i can write methods for the 'find_one' command easily ie:

```
@staticmethod
def find_one(collection, query):
    return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query)
```

however writing one to create an index throws an error, ie:

```
@staticmethod
def create_index(collection):
    return Database.DATABASE[collection].createIndex({ "type" : 1, "amount" : 1, "loss" : 1, "price" : 1, "create_date" : 1 }, {unique:true})
```

gives the error:

```
return Database.DATABASE[collection].createIndex({ "type" : 1, "amount" : 1, "loss" : 1, "price" : 1, "create_date" : 1 }, {unique:true})
NameError: name 'unique' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

The method for creating index in pymongo is `create_index`. You should do something like this -

```
my_collection.create_index([("type", pymongo.ASCENDING),("amount", pymongo.ASCENDING),("loss", pymongo.ASCENDING),("price", pymongo.ASCENDING),("create_date", pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)
```

Check the documentation [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.2/api/pymongo/collection.html)